# writing style format in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I am in bit confusion to adding parent style to new style. But both are working. But i want to know which is correct way first one or second one? or is there any other way ?

```
<style name="customView" parent="viewline">
    <item>....
```

and

```
<style name="customView" parent="@style/viewline">
<item>....
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

***Both are correct as you said.*** At here there is no any drawback to use any of them.

```
<style name="customView" parent="viewline">
```

denotes that the parent style is in same file. And

```
<style name="customView" parent="@style/viewline">
```

denotes that parent style is somewhere (may be i another file) in style directory. Thats it.